# navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems is not displayed on the root view controller when popToRootViewController is called

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, rightbarbuttonitem

In the final viewcontroller of my application, I use popToMainViewController to go back to the first view controller. When the method is called, customized rightBarButtonItems is not displayed. rightBarButtonItems work as expected when the mainViewController gets displayed for the first time after the application is started.

```swift
extension UINavigationController {
    func popToMainViewController(animated: Bool) {
        if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
           let rootController = windowScene.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
           let mainViewController = rootController.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is MainViewController }) {
            popToViewController(mainViewController, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

I use this code to go back to my MainViewController. The reason why I use this function is because I use customized LaunchScreen, MainViewController is the second viewcontroller in the navigation controller.

I call the method in

```swift
    @objc func callMainVC() {
        audioPlayerManager.stop()
        self.navigationController?.popToMainViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

In my MainViewController,

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        configureSettingBtn()
        configureNavBarItems()
    }

func configureSettingBtn() {
        let settingImage = UIImage(named: "settingIcon")
        let settingBtn = UIButton()
        settingBtn.setImage(settingImage, for: .normal)
        settingBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingApp), for: .touchUpInside)
        let setting = UIBarButtonItem(customView: settingBtn)
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [setting]
    }

private func configureNavBarItems() {
        print("configuring nav bar items")
        let spacer = createSpacer()
        
        let infoImage = UIImage(named: "infoIcon")
        let infoBtn = UIButton()
        infoBtn.setImage(infoImage, for: .normal)
        infoBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(guide), for: .touchUpInside)
        let info = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoBtn)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(contentsOf: [spacer, info])
    }
    
    @objc func guide() {
        let componentPositions: [CGRect] = [playerButton.frame, refereeButton.frame, hostButton.frame, gameWalkerImage.frame]
        let layerList: [CALayer] = [playerButton.layer, refereeButton.layer, hostButton.layer]
        let explanationTexts = ["Join as a team member", "Allocate points and manage individual games", "Organize and oversee the entire event"]
        
        let overlayViewController = MainOverlayViewController()
        overlayViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen // Present it as overlay
        overlayViewController.configureGuide(componentPositions, layerList, explanationTexts)
        
        present(overlayViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

These are my setUp for the navigation controller. hidesBackButton is set to `true`

[MAINVIEWCONTROLLER IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOyv6.png)
The screen should look like this, but when the popToMainViewController is called,
[Malfunctioning MainViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a61Sk.png)
The NavBarButtons are not displayed.

I tried Xcode menu Debug > View Debugging > Show View Frames, and I think navigationController does not exist. But I don't know how to resolve this problem
[show view frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKLmZ.png)

I tried

```swift
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.isNavigationHidden = false
self.navigationController?.setNavigationControllerHidden(false, animated: false)
```

Also tried debugging and confirmed that viewWillDisappear and methods in viewWillDisappear is called everytime I access MainViewController.
But When I call popToMainViewController, the customized navigation Item is not shown, and that occurs the same in following viewcontrollers.

I printed self.navigationController in viewWillAppear of the MainViewController. The same navigationController gets printed everytime I move to the MainViewController. Even when I call the popToMainViewController method, the same navigationController gets printed, but not displayed.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but if your MainViewController is also your navigation controller's root view controller, why not use `popToRootViewController()`? That would be simpler than the code in your `popToMainViewController()` function.

Comment: My first view controller in the navigation controller is custom LaunchScreenViewController. That's why

Comment: Should I remove LaunchScreenViewController and make the MainViewcontroller the root view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you are setting up your navigation items in `viewWillAppear`. View controllers on a navigation stack stick around, and `viewWillAppear` gets called again when you pop back to them. It looks to me like your `configureNavBarItems()` function is appending items to your `rightBarButtonItems`. Thus, when you go back to your `MainViewController`, you'll have duplicate `rightBarButtonItems`.

Try moving your navigation bar setup code to `viewDidLoad` rather than `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Already tried that, but doesn't work . I even tried the configureNavBarItems() inside the viewDidAppear, but that also doesn't work.

Comment: In any case you should not be adding items to your window's navigation item in ViewWillAppear since it will be called each time the view controller is displayed, and you'll add the same items more than once. I don't know WHAT problems that will cause, but it is likely to have some undesired impact.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your implementation. I just created a simple test project where my root view controller adds a right bar button item, and when I push another view controller onto it and then pop back to it, the right bar button is still visible as expected.

Comment: In my navigation flow, there is a tabbar controller. To customize the right bar button items of the viewcontrollers under the tabbar controller, I embedded a new navigation controller (on the storyboard) for each viewcontorllers under the tabbar controller. I move to the final view controller from the tabbar controller. Do you think that is related to this issue?

Comment: I created a simple test project, set up navigation flow almost the same as much as possible to the original project, and used the same function for going back to the main view controller.
It works as expected! I don't know why it's not working in my original project. I'm completely lost now

Comment: I was stupid. In my final view controller, I did

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }

and did not set it to false when viewWillDisappear.

I set it to false and problem solved. I really really appreciate your help and sorry to take up your time